Seifert invariants for Brieskorn manifolds $\Sigma(p,q,r)$
I've been studying Brieskorn manifolds $\Sigma(p,q,r)$ for $p,q,r\geq 2$. I know they are defined as the intersection of the complex surface $z_1^p+z_2^q+z_3^r=0$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^3$ and $S^5$, but I also know they are homeomorphic to the $r$-fold cyclic branched cover of $S^3$ branched along the torus link $T(p,q)$. Moreover, I know they are an example of Seifert fibered manifolds $M(b,(a_1,b_1),..., (a_n,b_n))$. I have seen that in Savaliev's "Invariants for homology 3-spheres", he considers the case in which $p,q,r$ are pairwise coprime, in which case $\Sigma(p,q,r)$ becomes a homology 3-sphere. For this case, he gives the condition $a_1\cdots a_n\cdot \sum b_k/a_k = 1+b\cdot a_1\cdots a_n$ to find the Seifert invariants $b_i$ when only the $a_i$'s are known. However, I am interested in the general case when the $a_i$'s may not be pairwise coprime. Is there a similar condition for $p,q,r$ not pairwise coprime that could allow one to find the Seifert invariants for a Brieskorn manifold?
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

This is written in Némethi's book Normal surface singularities, Example 5.1.17. (He actually talks about the more general case of complete intersections of Brieskorn-type.)
He refers to Jankins and Neumann's Lectures on Seifert manifolds and to Neumann and Raymond's Seifert manifolds, plumbing, $\mu$-invariant and orientation-reversing maps.
